# Are all cold observables unicast and all hot observables multicast?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am reading the documentation about [multicasting](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting) saying:

> In RxJS observables are **cold, or unicast** by default. These operators can make an observable **hot, or multicast**, allowing side-effects to be shared among multiple subscribers.

I wonder whether all cold observables are unicast and all hot are multicast, or whether there can be any exceptional cases.

Comment: check some explanation here: https://dev.to/michael_hladky/research-on-reactive-ephemeral-state-in-component-oriented-frameworks-38lk

Comment: I think they mean that all cold Observables build into RxJS are unicast which means they aren't shared (like N subscription will create N different chains). This doesn't imply that hot Observables are multicasted. You can just turn cold Observables into hot using multicasting operators.

Comment: The best explanation you could get about this topic is probably from Ben Lesh, one of the creators of RxJS, that can be found [here](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339).

Comment: @lagoman Added that to my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [link](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) provided by [@lagoman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253279/lagoman) (which I've read multiple times but still missed that point) I found some interesting explanation about hot-multicast relationship:

> ² **Hot observables** are usually multicast, but they **could be listening to a producer that only supports one listener at a time**. **The grounds** for calling it “multicast” at that point **are a little fuzzy**.